How do I add a javascript file in the default model form in admin.py?
I want to add a javascript function in the default model form that renders on the django admin site.
I do not have a separate html template that loads the form.
I have used the Media class inside the model form but where do I load it from?
Any clues?
I have created an 'Example' model in models.py. I have added additional fields to render on the admin panel.
admin.py
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = "__all__"
    
    username = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=False, max_length=100)

    class Media:
        js = ('static/app_name/js/custom.js',)

I looked for solutions online which asks to include the script tag in the html template.
But I am not using a template.
Assuming I have to add a template to add javascript on that form, which template do I use? I don't want to change the default design that django provides.

I have created the same idea before,
you should point the file path to the static of the same app that you put the code into its admin
example: add this code in admin.py
 class Media:
        js = [
            static('nnuh_doctors/admin/js/doctor_availability.js'),
        ]

and the app hierarchy should be like this:

